# QWebEnginePage handle NewWindowRequest?

Tags: c++, qt

That the important line of code for understanding:

```
QWebEngineView *web = new QWebEngineView;
QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage;
web->setPage(page);
page->load(QUrl("https://portal.premiertech.com/"));
```

and this is diplayed in normal QmainWindows like this

```
#include "fp.h"


fp::fp(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    //définition et parametre de la page webview
    web->setPage(page);
    page->load(QUrl("https://portal.premiertech.com/"));


    //parametre du tray icon
    QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":/ico/favicon.ico"));
    trayIcon->setToolTip("Pt Portal");

    QMenu *traymenu = new QMenu(this);
    QAction *viewWindow = new QAction(tr("Afficher Pt Portal"), this);
    QAction *quitAction = new QAction(tr("Fermer Pt Portal"), this);

    connect(viewWindow, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(show()));
    connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));

    traymenu->addAction(viewWindow);
    traymenu->addAction(quitAction);

    trayIcon->setContextMenu(traymenu);
    trayIcon->show();


    //fenetre a l'intérieux du mainwindows et son layout
    QWidget *inside = new QWidget;
    QGridLayout *gl = new QGridLayout;
    QPushButton *bt_next = new QPushButton;
    bt_next->setIcon(QIcon(":/ico/next.png"));
    QPushButton *bt_retour = new QPushButton;
    bt_retour->setIcon(QIcon(":/ico/back.png"));
    QPushButton *bt_refresh = new QPushButton;
    bt_refresh->setIcon(QIcon(":/ico/refresh.png"));
    QPushButton *bt_home = new QPushButton;
    bt_home->setIcon(QIcon(":/ico/home.png"));
    QPushButton *bt_masque = new QPushButton;
    bt_masque->setIcon(QIcon(":/ico/hide.png"));
    QPushButton *bt_quit = new QPushButton;
    bt_quit->setIcon(QIcon(":/ico/quit.png"));
    gl->addWidget(bt_masque,0,3);
    gl->addWidget(bt_home,0,4);
    gl->addWidget(bt_retour,0,5);
    gl->addWidget(bt_next,0,6);
    gl->addWidget(bt_refresh,0,7);
    gl->addWidget(bt_quit,0,8);
    gl->addWidget(web,1,0,10,11);
    inside->setLayout(gl);




    //définition des parametre de la fenetre principale

    setCentralWidget(inside);
    setMinimumSize(500, 350);
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":ico/favicon.ico"));
    setWindowTitle(tr("Pt Portal"));
    setFocus();

    //conect bt
    connect(bt_quit,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
    connect(bt_masque,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(hide()));
    connect(bt_masque,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(nw()));
    connect(bt_home,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(home()));
    connect(bt_next,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(next()));
    connect(bt_refresh,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(refresh()));
    connect(bt_retour,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(retour()));
   
    }


void fp::home()
{
    page->load(QUrl("https://portal.premiertech.com/"));

}

void fp::refresh()
{
    web->reload();
}

void fp::next()
{
    web->forward();
}

void fp::retour()
{
    web->back();
}
```

and actually i try to handle the posibily to open in new windows when requested by java i have try 2 method but nothing work

#1

```
connect(page,SIGNAL(newWindowRequested(QWebEngineNewWindowRequest)),this,SLOT(createWindow(QWebEngineNewWindowRequest)));
```

#2

```
connect(page,SIGNAL(newWindowRequested(QWebEngineNewWindowRequest)),this,SLOT(newwindow(QWebEngineNewWindowRequest)));

void mywindow::newwindow(QWebEngineNewWindowRequest *requestwindow)
    QWidget *mywidget= new QWidget;
    QGridLayout *mygridlayout= new QGridLayout;
    QWebEngineView *mywebview= new QWebEngineView;
    QWebEnginePage *mypage = new QWebEnginePage;
    
    mywebview->setPage(mypage);
    mygridlayout->addWidget(mywebview);

    requestwindow->openIn(mypage); //and i also try mypage->load(requestwindow->requestedUrl());

    mywidget->setLayout(mygridlayout);
    mywidget->show();
```

all of this option result in this error when i try to open new windows requested by java or by the rigth click action OpeninNewWindows:

```
ASSERT: "event->reason() != Qt::PopupFocusReason" in file \Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\webenginewidgets\render_widget_host_view_qt_delegate_widget.cpp, line 79
```

My question is how to handle it?
The 2 option which I named above look good or it should be sommething else?

Comment: Which version of `Qt` are you using?  The `newWindowRequested` signal wasn't available before [`Qt` 6.2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#newWindowRequested).  Possibly off topic but you really should be using the new signal/slot syntax to detect any type mismatches etc. at compile-time.

Comment: Im using the version 6.2.2